# Client's channel registration with Windows Azure

Tags: html, azure, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I'm trying to create this sample by myself:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn/Windows-8-Push-Notifications-with-Windows-Azure

I created the Push Notifications Registration Cloud Service (the project i created with vs2010) and it seemed to run ok.
Then I created the client project on vs 11 (Metro style app with JS and HTML5), ran it and tried to register a channel. It didn't work and wrote on screen "Registration not accepted" instead of the channel's uri.

What should I do?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

> > It didn't work and wrote on screen "Registration not accepted" instead of the channel's uri.

I would like to suggest you to use Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows 8: http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/. Then, try to compare your code with the sample code to find out where the issue is encountered.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Please make sure you’ve correctly registered your service on the Windows 8 portal. If not, you may encounter such errors. You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465407.aspx for more information.